# If Span(A)=Span(B) then $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let the be V a vector space and $A,B \subset V$ sub-sets of V.

If Span(A)=Span(B) then $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$

What I thought is that Span(A)=Span(B) mean that for all $a \in A$,$b \in B$ 

$\alpha_1a_1+...\alpha_na_n$=$\beta_1b_1+...\beta_nb_n$ does not says that A=B, but does to the reason both A and B Span a space, 0 $\in A,B$ and therefore $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$

Comment: This is false the way it's written down. Consider $A = \{(1,0)\}$ and $B = \{(2, 0)\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$ then $A\cap B = \emptyset$ but $\langle A \rangle = \langle B \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result doesn't need to be true. Consider the space $\Bbb R^2$ under the usual interpretation. let $A = \{(1, 1)\}$ and $B = \{(2, 2)\}$. The spans of $A$ and $B$ are equal and $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Comment: I got something fundamentally wrong, two sub-spaces intersection must at least be 0, but here A,B are just vectors so their intersection can be an empty set?